# MagicalRecord deleteObject not working

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Here is the code:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] save:&error];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
```

When I delete an object, the collection view reloads and the object is gone. However, the next time I run the app, the object shows up again. What else do I need to do to delete it permanently?

EDIT:
I also tried this after deleteObject:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

The object still shows up the next time I run the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *obj = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:index];
[obj MR_deleteEntityInContext:context];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. But can you explain how this is different from what I was doing and why this works?

Comment: Assuming this forces the database to complete the deletion immediately, rather than on it's lunch break.